# Change what remote branch a local is associated with?

Tags: git, git-rebase, gitkraken

I am maintaining a branch in a git repo (the local/remote in the diagram). The code I worked on in the local version of the branch actually belongs in the other branch (Branch 2 in the diagram).

Unfortunately, while I had not pushed my local commit of the branch, another developer pushed their version which created the situation in the original diagram.

In order to attempt to fix it, I rebased my local copy onto Branch 2.
However, my local copy is still associated with it's original remote branch.

I would like to associate it with Branch 2 and then push, to get the outcome in the desired diagram.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Branch Diagram]

Comment: Your hand-drawn diagram is very hard to read. Is that "Branch" or "Branch2" on the far left? Can you convert it into ASCII art? It would help future readers immensely.

Comment: Whatever you do...if you want to not mess things up and you're working with other developers, be careful to never "rewrite history".  This means making a change to the tree that will break some other developer's local copy. If a remote "Branch 2" is something that already exists and some other developer has pulled from, and then you want to replace that remote branch with a different definition, that's "rewriting history".   if "Branch 2" does not yet exist, or no other developer has pulled from it, then you're fine. - Otherwise, pull that branch, merge your changes to it, and push it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a local branch to a branch with different name, you just do `git push remoterepo localbranch:remotebranch`.

If you need to change the upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to=remotebranch localbranch`.

Comment: you can add another remote repo in your config of local repository with `git remote add {nickname} <remote_branch>` . Then when you execute push/pull you can specify wich remote you will use with `git [ push | pull ] {nickname}`

Answer (score 0):

As this question is tagged with "gitkraken" here is how you do it in GitKraken:

- right click on the local branch (either in the Graph View or the left side panel)
- select "Set Upstream"
- set the remote repo and branch name in the prompt and click "Submit"

If you want to push your local branch to a different remote branch only once you can drag and drop your local branch on the remote branch and select "Push local to origin/remote".

The explanation on the GitKraken site: [https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/problems/git-set-upstream-branch#:~:text=With%20GitKraken%2C%20it's%20easy%20to,push%20instead%20of%20setting%20upstream](https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/problems/git-set-upstream-branch#:%7E:text=With%20GitKraken%2C%20it%27s%20easy%20to,push%20instead%20of%20setting%20upstream).